# Trying to find LCM using recursion...I get infinity

Tags: javascript, recursion

EDIT** Reading my question, I realize now why I get infinity, num2 and num1 will never be equal since num2 will always be a larger number. Is it possible to solve this using recursion or is it better to use something like a loop? I'm able to solve this, just curious about recursion.

If both numbers are the same, I should have found the LCM and want to return it. If they are not equal, I'll call my function again, but with each increased by its original value.

```
 let leastCommonMultiple = (num1, num2) => {
    if (num1 === num2) return num1;

    return leastCommonMultiple(num1 + num1, num2 + num2)
}

console.log(leastCommonMultiple(4, 6)); // 12
console.log(leastCommonMultiple(3, 5)); // 15
console.log(leastCommonMultiple(2, 10)); // 10
```

Comment: This algorithm will not work.  Where did you get it from and/or why did you think that it would produce the LCM?>

Comment: I'm aware it does not work. I wrote it. Is my understanding of why it does not work correct? I'm also trying to set a third parameter and increment by 1 each call of the function. My base case being, return n when is % num1 && n % num2 equal 0.

Comment: You can easily write a recursive GCD function.  Once you have that, then you can just write `const lcm = (a, b) => a / gcd (a, b) * b`.

Comment: I think RBarryYoung was pointing out that this wasn't simply an implementation issue.  It's fundamentally broken for many reasons.

Comment: Okay, so I need a helper function? I can't do this with just one function?

Comment: You can.  I'm just not sure you'd want to.  Let me write a quick answer.

Comment: Yes, @ScottSauyet is right, what I was saying is not that you code does not work, but rather that *it can not work*.  There's no way to fix it because it's not an algorithm that finds the LCD.  Really all it does is to double the 2 arguments every recursion.  As far as I know, that doesn't have anything to do with the LCD, so you need a different approach/algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly *can* write a recursive version of this.  Here's one particular inelegant and inefficient version:

```js
const lcm = (a, b, x = a, y = b) =>
  x == y 
    ? x 
    : x + a > y + b 
      ? lcm (a, b, x, y + b) 
      : lcm (a, b, x + a, y)

console .log (lcm (660, 126)) //=> 13860
```

We use `x` and `y` as continuing multiples of `a` and `b` respectively, increasing the smaller one until it's as least as large as the other.  When they're equal, you've hit the LCM.

With a little thought, I'm sure we could make this more efficient by multiplying the right factor.  But I'm not sure there's any good reason for this when GCD is so straightforward to do efficiently.

### Update

Here is a more efficient version:

```js
const lcm = (a, b, x = a, y = b) =>
  x == y 
    ? x 
    : x > y 
      ? lcm (a, b, x, b * Math.ceil (x / b)) 
      : lcm (a, b, a * Math.ceil (y / a), y)

console .log (lcm (660, 126)) //=> 13860
```

This uses something vaguely analogous to the modulo operator you would use for GCD, finding the first multiple of one value at least as large as another.  This should be relatively efficient.

### Update 2

To show how the ternaries work, this is an equivalent more imperative version:

```js
const lcm = (a, b, x = a, y = b) => {
  if (x == y) {
    return x
  } else {
    if (x > y) {
      return lcm (a, b, x, b * Math.ceil (x / b)) 
    } else {
      return lcm (a, b, a * Math.ceil (y / a), y)
    }
  }
}

console .log (lcm (660, 126)) //=> 13860
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to study this. I am very new to js and don't even know how ternary works, so I'll refer to MDN for that.

Comment: `condition ? consequent : alternative` works the same as `if (condition) {return consequent} else {return alternative}`, just as a plain expression rather than as a combination of the control flow construct statement, `if`, and the `return` statement.  It only works when you can put plain expressions in each of the three places,, but when you can, it's often cleaner.